# How does this Matlab code work?

Tags: matlab, rms, code, convolution

I came across this uncommented Matlab code except for the header:

```
*************************************
function y=movingvar(X,N)
% y=movingvar(X,N)
% Calculates N-point moving variance of Vector X
% Highly recommend that N be odd (no error checking)
% Note: first and last N/2 points will be unreliable.
% Output will be a column vector.
% Authors: Scott Seidman (scott.seidman@rochester.edu) 1/23/99

X=X(:);
XSQR=X.*X;
convsig=ones(1,N);
y=(conv(convsig,XSQR)-(conv(convsig,X).^2)/N)/(N-1);

y=y(ceil(N/2):length(X)+floor(N/2));
****************************************************
```

(from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/39521)

According to the comments here, it can also be used as a realtime RMS calculator: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/135276/53375

I can see that being useful, but I don't understand Matlab.  Could someone please explain what's going on?

I'm academically familiar with convolution, and I do know C.

Comment: Amazing find!!  I was pretty active in that forum some years ago.  I'll do my best to reconstruct it, but might take a few days.  Not that its variance, and not sd, which would require a square root.

Comment: Note its really a one liner, after creating a squared array: y=(conv(convsig,XSQR)-(conv(convsig,X).^2)/N)/(N-1);    The rest is just about shaving off the ends

Comment: @ScottSeidman LOL must be weird to have your code show up in places like this, and be able to deal with it. Awesome. I think stack overflow could have answered this one without you though.

Comment: @KyranF -- Not sure if SO is the place for this -- it's not really a programming question, more of an algorithm question.  Probably DSP is a better target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the formula for sample variance 
$$ s^{2}=\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left ( X_{i}-\bar{X} \right )^2}{N-1} $$

you multiply out to get
$$ s^{2}=  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left({X_i}^2-2X_i
\bar{X}+\bar{X}^2\right )}{N-1} $$

Distribute the sums.  Using the fact that \$ \bar{X}\$ is a constant, then $$ \sum 2X_i \bar{X} = 2\bar{X}\sum{X_i}, $$ and $$\sum{X_i}=N\bar{X},$$

So, $$ 2\bar{X}\sum{X_i}=2N\bar{X}^2.$$

Then, using $$ \sum_{i=1}^{N}\bar{X}^2=N\bar{X}^2, $$ and
$$ N\bar{X}^2 = \frac{ N\left( \sum{X} \right )^2}{N^2}  $$

the overall equation for varance  reduces to a convenient computational formula for variance:
$$ \frac{ \sum_{i-1}^{N}\left ( X_{i}^2 \right )-\frac{\left (\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i  \right )^2}{N}}{N-1} $$

XSQR=X.*X;  \ simply element by element squares the column array, X

Without entirely explaining convolution, convolution with a string of ones of length N (i.e., convsig) is simply a sum of the previous N points at each time step.

The last line in the code just gets rid of the trash at either end of the array associated with the beginning and end of convolution.

Lastly, you need to understand that most operations on arrays in Matlab operate on the whole array at the same time -- most of the operations in the program you show would absolutely need to loop over every element in the array in a language like C, which likely very confusing for folks not used to working in Matlab.

Bottom line, its not much different than actually just implementing the sum, but convolution is something directly written into matlab, and there are generally libraries that directly handle convolution on DSP's, so its a convenient way to implement a moving variance filter without needing to do the grunt work.

Comment: Okay, so it's not actually different under the hood than what you'd brute-force in C; you're just taking advantage of Matlab's libraries.  Right?

Comment: Also, isn't it supposed to be Xi^2 in your first equation instead of Xi^1?

Comment: @AaronD, Exactly-- but there will be good libraries for doing this in real time on DSP's as well.  Had the square inside the paren instead of outside.  Fixed now.

Comment: I think I get it now.  I'm not sure I follow you from the second equation to the third, especially the second term of the numerator.  But if I take Xbar to be zero, then it becomes the standard RMS equation, which is all I need, and your method of solving it still works.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can edit an answer after it's accepted, so I'll leave it open for a while so you can show some more steps between 2 and 3 if you'd like.

Comment: You can always edit an answer, but I added the interim steps and corrected a bad minus sign.  I took the liberty of leaving out the summation boundaries.  My LaTex is now much better!

Comment: Oh, Xbar is the mean, not an arbitrary reference.  I got it now.  Thank you!